# Java - jList sometimes not updating correctly?

Tags: java, swing

This is my code:

```
DefaultListModel modelPlayers = (DefaultListModel)Game.window.jListPlayers.getModel();
DefaultListModel modelPlayersGame = (DefaultListModel)Game.window.jListPlayersInGame.getModel();
modelPlayers.clear();
modelPlayersGame.clear();
for(String s : getPlayersFromArray(p.content[0]))
{
     modelPlayers.addElement(s);
     modelPlayersGame.addElement(s);
}


private String[] getPlayersFromArray(String array)
{
    return array.split(",");
}
```

Sometimes the content of the list simply disappears and then it appears again (after another update).

I have checked that `p.content[0]` always contained something like `player1, player2` so that should not be the problem.

Comment: which list are you talking about?

Comment: @Reservoir Sampling Game.window.jListPlayersInGame

Comment: @MPirious Yeah I did, its mentioned in the question.

Comment: You may be blocking the EDT. Check [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: @Ladas125 that is because you are doing `modelPlayers.clear();
modelPlayersGame.clear();` and it does not make any sense to do `.clear()` just after getting some value.

Comment: @Reservoir Sampling But I am adding the new content immediately after clearing.

Comment: @Ladas125 My point was in the above code, what `Game.window.jListPlayers` contains does not matter at all.

Comment: @Codebender Thank you, looks like it was really caused by calling swing from another thread!

Comment: @ReservoirSampling also thank you for trying to help!